# Deeper analytics for Azure Static Web Apps?

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

Is it possible to access analytics such as browser, dates and times of site hits, IP addresses, etc.?

From the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings#types-of-application-settings), it looks like Azure App Insights are only available for Static Web Apps that use Azure Functions. I just have a static website, no API's.

**Here is the message I'm shown when trying to enable App Insights:**
[image]

Ideally, I want to set a `Diagnostic Setting` and use Azure Log Analytics to view analytics.

How can I get deeper analytics on a Static Web App without a Function API?

**EDIT 1:** I'd like to at least capture the number of hits somewhere.

- Azure Metrics is grabbing them, but doesn't seem to expose logs anywhere, only these visualizations.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if azure app insights can meet all your analytic requirement, but if you are deploying a static web app written by angular,react, etc, you may use code-based method to integrate app insights, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#adding-the-javascript-sdk  Hence, could you pls add more details on your static web app? I mean how you writing your app, which framework is used...

Comment: I believe its a javascript tool. Its a turnkey site, so minimal dev required. [Squido](https://docs.squido.org) static blog.

Comment: @TinyWang, do you know how to get to the raw Azure Metric data logs as shown in **EDIT 1** above?

Comment: `SiteHits` seems to be a [custom metric](https://carldesouza.com/how-to-create-custom-events-metrics-traces-in-azure-application-insights-using-c/), and you can see my test https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu8p8.png   How to add trackmetric:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#single-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ended up going with:**

- A stand-alone Application Insights instance

  - Azure Static Apps does not allow App Insights to be turned on for the resource unless there is an Azure Function involved(?)
- Added this App Insights [Javascript snippet](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup) to each page of the static site.

Got some great help from [@MSNEV](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1594)!

This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I also have the same problem... I tried adding one dummy api function, then I was able to deploy appinsights. Still, this seems to only track api related requests, no GET requests for the static sites... A well I might just go with standalone storage static site hosting.

Comment: The JavaScript snippet above works well without have to deploy a dummy function.